# casestovars - only some, but not all variables restructured

Tags: variables, case, transformation, partial, spss

I restructured my data with the CASESTOVARS command, but the data was only transformed/restructered partially. That means, some variables resulted restructured, but others not.

This is how the structure from the original data set looks like:

```
╔═════════╦══════╦════════╦════════╦═════╦═════╦═════╦══════╦═══════╗
║ Pelgges ║ pbnr ║ mszpkt ║ cohort ║ Sex ║ PW1 ║ PW2 ║ Bez1 ║  Bez2 ║
╠═════════╬══════╬════════╬════════╬═════╬═════╬═════╬══════╬═══════╣
║ 230     ║ 1    ║ 1      ║ 4      ║ 1   ║ 4   ║ 3   ║ 4    ║ 0     ║
║ 12      ║ 1    ║ 2      ║ 4      ║ 1   ║ 3   ║ 2   ║ 3    ║ 1     ║
║ 44      ║ 1    ║ 3      ║ 4      ║ 1   ║ 4   ║ 2   ║ 3    ║ 1     ║
║ 25      ║ 2    ║ 1      ║ 1      ║ 0   ║ 2   ║ 1   ║ 1    ║ 3     ║
║ 765     ║ 2    ║ 2      ║ 1      ║ 0   ║ 1   ║ 2   ║ 2    ║ 2     ║
║ 985     ║ 2    ║ 3      ║ 1      ║ 0   ║ 1   ║ 1   ║ 1    ║ 2     ║
╚═════════╩══════╩════════╩════════╩═════╩═════╩═════╩══════╩═══════╝


pbnr = subject number
mszpkt= time of measurement
cohort=cohort number
sex= sex 
PW1, PW2, Bez1, Bez2 = Variables that should split up by mszpkt.
```

And I used this syntax for transforming the structure the way that the subject number just occurs once, not for every time of measurement:

```
CASESTOVARS
/ID=pbnr
/INDEX = mszpkt
/DROP pelgges cohort Sex.
list.
EXECUTE.
```

In the Outputfile PW1 didnt split up into PW1.1, PW1.2 and PW1.3, but the other three variables did.
Has anyone an idea why this could have happened?

The warning that was shown was the following:

The cases are not sorted. The first sequence error occured in case number 4. The results could be wrong.

Here I'd like to specify my problem, because it worked with the example above, but not in the original data. Here I posted a small sample from the real data where the problem still comes up:

```
pelgges pbnr mszpkt cohort sex Bez1 Status2
715       36    2      2    0    1    0
716       174   3      5    1    3    0
717       85    2      3    1    2    0
226        1    1      1    0    1    0
590        1    4      1    0    2    0
131        2    4      1    0    1    0
1297       2    2      1    0       
9999      34    1      2    1    1    1
9998      34    2      2    1    2    1
```

And it resulted the following:

```
pbnr Status2 Bez1.1 Bez1.2 Bez1.4 Bez1.4
36     0                1       
174    0                      3 
85     0                2       
1      0         1                  2
2      0                            1
34     1         1      2
```

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me, as expected (with all PW1, PW2, Bez1 and Bez2 forming 3 sets of variables):

```
DATA LIST FREE /  Pelgges pbnr mszpkt cohort Sex PW1 PW2 Bez1 Bez2 .
BEGIN DATA
 230 1 1 4 1 4 3 4 0 
 12 1 2 4 1 3 2 3 1 
 44 1 3 4 1 4 2 3 1 
 25 2 1 1 0 2 1 1 3 
 765 2 2 1 0 1 2 2 2 
 985 2 3 1 0 1 1 1 2 
END DATA.


CASESTOVARS
/ID=pbnr
/INDEX = mszpkt
/DROP pelgges cohort Sex.
```

Make sure in your actually data `PW1` is not a constant within each ID `pbnr`(across all index values `mszpkt`). If so, then `CASESTOVARS` would not expand out that variable by default.

Comment: thank you for your response. You are right, this example works. As it is only a small part of my datasheet it works here, but not in my real data.
 I put up an example where the error still comes up, but where I dont have to upload the whole data. So I reduced my data to only two variables. These Variables are called Bez1 and Status2 (for the data see above, I edited my question). Although Status2 doesnt have lots of variance, its not a constant, but it still doesnt split up...
I am thankful for responses!

Comment: I would expect that (`Status` not to split) as `Status` is constant within groups of `pnbr` cases.

Comment: @Sophie: Have you experimented with the `/fixed` and `/autofix` subcommands subcommand ? SPSS tries to automatically determine which variables should be re-structured and which not. So when it found PW1 to be a constant, it would automatically exclude it from the re-structuring process. In your case, it should work if you just add `/autofix=no`